# Customize view controller transition animation timing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

Is there a way I can easily change the duration of the transition animation between view controllers? For example if I call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES can I also give an option to control how long that transition occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. You can, though, tell `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` to not animate, and then animate yourself using `transitionWithView`, e.g.,

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.superview
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                animations:^{
                    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Obviously, use whatever `duration` and `options` work best for you.

Comment: Try it out. I think you'll find it does the job for you.

Comment: But if you do dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO then viewDidAppear will be called immediately on the following view controller, even before transitionWithView gets done animating. In other words, the timing will be off.

Comment: @yourfriendzak, it seems to work fine, but I take your point. If you had timing specific stuff, you could probably use the completion block. Otherwise, just stick with the default transition timing.